# Smartsheet API change? Bad Request Error related to Index format type

Tags: python, python-3.x, smartsheet-api

I have a piece of software that utilizes the Smartsheet API (specifically the Python SDK). I recently realized that the Smartsheet connectivity of the software has been broken since mid-January and as far as I can tell it’s due to a change on the Smartsheet side of things. I even rolled back to a version I know to have worked previously (the version that resulted from help in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216697/updating-cell-format-using-smartsheet-api-python-sdk)).

Here is the code I use to access the sheet:

```
#Now query the smartsheet server
try:

    # Load entire sheet
    sheet = ss.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id, include=['format'],
                                page_size=500)
    logging.info("Loaded "+str(len(sheet.rows))+
                    " rows from sheet: "+sheet.name)
    column_map = {}
    # Build column map for later reference-translates
    # column names to column id
    for column in sheet.columns:
        column_map[column.title] = column.id
    # Helper function to find cell in a row i a smartsheet object
    def get_cell_by_column_name(row, column_ame):
        column_id = column_map[column_ame]
        return row.get_column(column_id)
    # Find first row that hasn't already been written to
    newrowindex = [row.row_number 
                for row in sheet.rows
            if get_cell_by_column_name(row,
                'Column4').display_value != None][-1]
    # Build the row to update
    newRow = ss.models.Row()
    newRow.id = sheet.rows[newrowindex].id
    for col in sheet.columns:
        newCell = ss.models.Cell()
        newCell.column_id = col.id
        newCell.value = df[sheet.rows[2].get_column(
                            col.id).display_value
                                           ].loc[1]
        oldformat = sheet.rows[newrowindex].get_column(
                            col.id).format
        if oldformat == None:
            oldformat = ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
        newformat = oldformat.split(',')[:-3]
        newformat = "".join([ii+',' for ii in 
                              newformat])[:-1]

        newformat = (newformat + df_fmts[
                            sheet.rows[2].get_column(
                            col.id).display_value
                                           ].loc[1])
        newCell._format = newformat
        newRow.cells.append(newCell)
    newRow.cells[0].value = sheet.rows[newrowindex].cells[0].value
    newRow.cells[2].value = fieldinputs.projectid
    result = ss.Sheets.update_rows(sheet_id,[newRow])
    smshtexportButton.button_type = "success"
    smshtexportButton.label = "Sucessfully Published!"
```

Here is the resulting error log:

```
Request: {
command: GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/7120922902587268?
include=format&pageSize=500&page=1
}
2018-02-16 09:53:00,378 Loaded 205 rows from sheet: Bulk Update
2018-02-16 09:53:01,126 Request: {
command: PUT https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/7120922902587268/rows
}
2018-02-16 09:53:01,134 Response: {
status: 400 Bad Request
content: {
{
    "detail": {
        "index": 0,
        "rowId": 6710889537660804
    },
    "errorCode": 1008,
    "message": "Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Index 
value '11' is invalid for format type DECIMAL_COUNT",
   "refId": "1upixmmo45bp3"
}
}
```

The last successful update the software made to the 'Bulk Update' sheet was 1/16/18 at 3:37pm PST. I initially suspected that I had made changes to the `df` and `df_fmts` dataframes in the code above, but upon reverting back to the same version of the code used on 1/16, I still get the Bad Request error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since this seems to be a bug/issue with the Smartsheet API, I'd suggest that you report it to Smartsheet directly by emailing api@smartsheet.com. (Doing so should enable them to open & assign a ticket/case internally for investigating this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Smartsheet app the furthest you can set decimal places is 5. Anything greater than that will return an error like you are seeing. According to the error you are setting the decimal places to be 11, which is unsupported.
I suggest looking at your code that sets the format and how it is getting to 11. Then make sure the decimal place never goes above 5.